# Show/Hide Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in the React and I am trying to make a sidebar with a navigation menu. When user click on the li tag with className "frist", the component FrstComponent opens, when user click on the li tag with className "second" SecondComponent opens etc. Like bootstrap tabs.
This is my code

```
    class Navigation extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       isActive: "first"
    }
    this.handleClickChange =this.handleClickChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleClickChange(){
    this.setState={
        isActive: !this.state.isActive
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {active} = this.state.isActive
    if(active === 'first'){
      return <FristComponent/>
    }
    if(active === 'second'){
      return <SecondComponent/>
    }
    return (
      <div>
      <ul>
        <li 
        className="first"
        onClick={this.handleClickChange} 
        >
          FIRST

        </li>
        <li 
          className="second"   
          onClick={this.handleClickChange}
          >
          SECOND
        </li>
        <li className="third">THIRD</li>
        <li className="fourth">FOURTH</li>
        <li className="fifth">FIFTH</li>
      </ul>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Navigation />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/6v9vorn33w

Answer (score 3):

i'm trying to help you, but your code need more refactoring :)

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Navigation extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: "first"
  }

  handleClickChange = e => {
    const { className } = e.target

    this.setState({ active: className})
  }

  render() {
    const { active } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        {active === 'first' && <div>First Component</div>}

        {active === 'second' && <div>Second Component</div>}

        <ul>
          <li className="first"
            onClick={this.handleClickChange}
          >
            FIRST

        </li>
          <li
            className="second"
            onClick={this.handleClickChange}
          >
            SECOND
        </li>
          <li className="third">THIRD</li>
          <li className="fourth">FOURTH</li>
          <li className="fifth">FIFTH</li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Navigation />, rootElement);
```

You need to pass on **className** to state and check this variable when you rendering. If you have a questions by this code, you can ask :)

Comment: Just a little note for you while saying constructor(props) and super(props) and this.state is perfectly valid what he has above "state = { active: "first"} " 100% the same but it is syntax sugar and does the constructor and super for you by running it through babel